# Is there an fmod in theano?

Tags: python, theano

I am trying to work with images in the HSV colorspace. Since the hue channel is cyclic I wanted to have it normalized between 0 and 1.  I plan on using a linear activation on the output layer.  Is there a way to add another layer which clamps the output in a cyclic way.  Such as 1.02 -> 0.02?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an extra activation (not another layer) to your linear activation

```
linear_activation = ..... # your code to calculate linear activation
cyclic_linear_activation = theano.tensor.switch(linear_activation > 1.0, 
                                                linear_activation % 1.0,
                                                linear_activation)
```

`theano.tensor.switch` will check that the activation is greater than 1.0, before changing it to x mod 1.0 and it will do so separately for each element in `linear_activation`

***edit***

To deal with negatives in the same way you deal with the positives, you can do the following

```
theano.tensor.switch(cyclic_linear_activation < 0.0, 
                     (cyclic_linear_activation % 1.0) + 1.0,
                     cyclic_linear_activation )
```

Comment: How would I deal with negatives?  Like -0.01 -> 0.99

Comment: I made a mistake in the first one I fixed it and added an edit to include your negative case